# Widestring to string conversion in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, unicode, localization, delphi-7, ansi

my app is a non-unicode app written in Delphi 7.

I'd like to convert unicode strings to ANSI with this function :

```
function convertU(ws : widestring) : string;
begin
  result := string(ws);
end;
```

I use also this code to set the right codepage to convert.

```
initialization
  SetThreadLocale(GetSystemDefaultLCID);
  GetFormatSettings;
```

It works great in the VCL main thread but not in a TThread, 
where I get some questions marks **'?'** as result of function **convertU**.

Why not in a TThread ?

Comment: First, you don't need a function or typecast to do this; a simple `stringVar := wideStringVar;` will work. Second, the problem is that not all WideChars are directly convertible to an AnsiString; some are more than one character in width, and some have character values that are not representable in an AnsiChar, and some fonts don't contain all possible Unicode values. If you're *seeing* `?`, it means you're displaying them, which could be the third problem - threads should not access GUI controls without using `Sychronize`. Since you didn't post the display code, it's hard to say if that's it.

Comment: The question is :
why do I get question marks 
when used in a TThread ?

Comment: I repeat: **If you're seeing `?`, you're displaying the text.** You've provided **zero code or information** regarding how you're displaying it.

Comment: I have a look on the returned values with the debugger

Comment: Is a TThread aware of system default LCID ?

Comment: ? is what you get when a conversion of a codepoint from Unicode to MBCS fails. Since you are talking about the contents of an AnsiString, and since ? Is in the common ASCII range, we can rule out display bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `SetThreadLocale()` inside of an `initialization` block has no effect on `TThread`.  If you want to set a thread's locale, you have to call `SetThreadLocale()` inside of the `TThread.Execute()` method.

A better option is to not rely on `SetThreadLocale()` at all.  Do your own conversion by calling `WideCharToMultiByte()` directly so you can specify the particular Ansi codepage to convert to.

Comment: If you are the author of all code in your app then explicit calls to WideCharToMultiByte is a viable option. If you include third party code, then thread-wide setting of the locale may be the best compromise.

Comment: yes. thanks. I use a mix of both now : WideCharToMultiByte AND SetThreadLocale()

Comment: Because I started to use WideCharToMultiByte first, but I think I will remove calls to this function and only use SetThreadLocale for each thread.

Comment: AFAIK `SetThreadLocale` does not change the current system Code Page, so won't affect the widestring to ansistring conversion in Delphi 7, which rely on `GetACP` API call.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK `SetThreadLocale` does not change the current system Code Page, so won't affect the `widestring` to `ansistring` conversion in Delphi 7, which rely on `GetACP` API call, i.e. the system Code Page.

The system Code Page is set e.g. in Windows Seven in the Control Panel, then Region Languages / Administrative tab / Code Page for non Unicode Applications. This needs a system restart.

Delphi 7 uses this system Code Page, supplying 0 to all conversion API calls. So AFAIR `SetThreadLocale` won't affect the `widestring` to `ansistring` conversion in Delphi 7. It will change the locale (e.g. date/time and currency formatting), not the code page used by the system for its Ansi <-> Unicode conversion.

Newer versions of Delphi have a `SetMultiByteConversionCodePage()` function, able to set the code page to be used for all `AnsiString` handling.

But API calls (i.e. all `....A()` functions in *Windows.pas* which are mapped by `...()` in Delphi 7) will use this system code page. So you will have to call the `...W()` wide API after a conversion to Unicode if you want to handle another code page. That is, the Delphi 7 VCL will work only with the system code page, not the value specified by `SetThreadLocale`.

Under Delphi 7, my advice is:

- Use `WideString` everywhere, and specific "Wide" API calls - there are several set of components for Delphi 7 which handle `WideString`;
- Use your own types, with a dedicated charset, but you'll need an explicit conversion before using the VCL/RTL or "Ansi" API calls - e.g. `MyString = type AnsiString` (this is what we do in mORMot, by defining a custom `RawUTF8` type for internal UTF-8 process).

This is much better handled with Delphi 2009 and up, since you can specify a code page to every `AnsiString` type, and properly handle conversion to/from Unicode, for API calls or VCL process.

Comment: I just want to handle the default system codepage. What I've noticed, is that for Unicode<->Ansi conversion, the codepage used is the DEFAULT user LCID and not the DEFAULT system LCID and that's an issue.